# Why this correlated subquery works differently in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have table EMPLOYEES with columns employee_id, department_id, salary (standard HR schema).

Why this query:

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    department_id,
    salary,
    (
        select min(EMPLOYEES.salary) 
        from HR.EMPLOYEES E 
        where department_id = EMPLOYEES.department_id
    )
from HR.EMPLOYEES;
```

Executes in Oracle but returns an error in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you please give us a hint by what you mean by "Works in Oracle but does not work in SQL Server?"

Comment: My bad: "Executes in Oracle but returns an error in SQL Server" is much more precise. But I have received the answer already.

Comment: Ok a more descriptive post would be help include the actual error message. This was any easy one but in the future the problem may not be so apparent. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow outer query references in aggregations in correlated subqueries.  That is usually fine, because such constructs are not usually very useful.  I'm pretty sure the error message says something like that.

I think this is the query you actually want:

```
select e.employee_id, e.department_id, e.salary,
       (select min(e2.salary)
        from HR.EMPLOYEES E2
        where e2.department_id = e.department_id
       )
from HR.EMPLOYEES e;
```

I *would* advise you to qualify all column references, particularly in a correlated subquery.

Your version would just return the salary of each employee in the outer query.  You don't need a correlated subquery to do that.

Comment: "SQL Server does not allow outer query references in aggregations in correlated subqueries."

And you answered my question. 
The error message says exactly that.
Of course I do not need a correlated subquery to do that, I was just surprised why there is a difference between Oracle and SQL Server..

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the `department_id` column in the subquery, otherwise it is ambibuous to which table it refers. Some RDBMS might allow your syntax, but I am unsure that this would produce the proper results.

It would also be a good idea to give an alias to the value returned by the subquery.

Hence:

```
select
    employee_id,
    department_id,
    salary,
    (
        select min(e1.salary) 
        from hr.employees e1 
        where e1.department_id = e.department_id
    ) min_department_salary
from hr.employees e;
```

Also, please note that you can get the same result without a subquery by using a window function (which both Oracle and SQLServer have been supporting for a long time):

```
select
    employee_id,
    department_id,
    salary,
    min(salary) over(partition by department_id) min_department_salary
from hr.employees e;
```